# Update Test On Controller Breaks in Rails 4.1.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm upgrading a Rails site from 4.0 to 4.1.12 and quite a few of my Rspec controller tests are now broken.  For example this test broke with the upgrade:

```
it "update action should render edit template" do
  @user = create(:user)
  @user.name = "" # model requires name
  @controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@user)
  put :update, id: @user
  expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
end
```

I'm getting "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]".  It seems like the update_attributes method is ignoring my model validations all of a sudden.

Controller code:

```
 def update
   @user = current_user
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => "Your profile has been updated."
   else
     render :action => 'edit'
   end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'accounting'
  end

  collection do
    post 'send_password'
  end
end
```

I'm sure I've missed something in the upgrade process but I don't see anything in the docs that's telling me what that is.

Comment: We are missing your `routes.rb`

Comment: Looking at the error it's actually routing to 'show' not 'update', as Fire-Dragon-DoL says would need to see your routes.  But my first thought was around you using 'put' to reach update rather than Rails 4 standard 'patch'.

Comment: Still could do with more code really.  Looking closer at the error it's actually routing to accounts#show and I'm assuming from the routes you've given you are testing the users controller.  So is there a redirect (e.g. before_action) happening the users controller somewhere?

Comment: I added the routes but that "No route matches" is happening when it tries to redirect after a successful save.  Unfortunately, it shouldn't be successful and should render "edit" instead.

Comment: Ahh ok - If you pass in an empty hash (you aren't passing anything for params[:user] in your test) then wont update_attributes return true?

Comment: If that's a dead end then I'd definitely be looking at how your strong parameters or protected attributes is setup.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on to something, I need to change how I'm calling patch and actually pass in the updated attributes for validation.

Comment: Yeah from your test it looks like you actually want something like `patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: '' }` then your update_attributes should fail validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to put down what I would do - rather than changing the @user object in the test you need to send in the changes you want to make to the user object as params of the request.  This way the controller would receive it in the params[] hash - otherwise you aren't really testing what the controller method is doing.

```
it "with invalid data; update action should render edit template" do
  @user = create(:user)
  @controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@user)
  patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: '' }
  expect(response).to render_template(:edit)
end
```

Comment: Yep, I think this was the right way to go.  I was doing too much state manipulation before in the controller.  Final controller looks like this     def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => "Your profile has been updated."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end